# How do you express a periodic/repeating decimal in expanded notation, especially algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, decimal-expansion

Let's just say you've been given an assignment to write a number like **0.435435435...** in expanded notation. How would you proceed? And how to generalize something like this with algebra?

Thank you very much.

### EDIT

Example of expanded notation of a number is on the right side of the following equation:

$0.435 = \left(4\times{}10^{-1}\right) + \left(3\times{}10^{-2}\right) + \left(5\times{}10^{-3}\right)$

The problem is that as soon as we draw a line above the entire sum of these products to try to denote repetition in algebraic form, the line would be perceived (unlike intended) as a grouping symbol.

I apologize for not clarifying things initially.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*expanded notation*", and I don't know of a universally standard notation for repeating decimals. I've seen $0.\overline{435}$ used in many places, or $0.\overline{d_1d_2d_3}$ for arbitrary decimal digits $d_{1,2,3}$, or $0.\overline{b_1b_2b_3}_{\,2}$ for repeating $b_{1,2,3}$ binary digits. I've also seen $0.(435)$ used, or $0.435435\ldots$ as you wrote. Point is that you should expect a clear definition of the notation *before* it's used in places that rely on it.

Comment: If you mean, how do you write a repeating decimal as a fraction? that has been asked and answered on this site many times over; please do a search for previous occurrences of the question.

Answer (score 2):

In "expanded notation",
$$
.435435435\dots=4\times10^{-1}+3\times10^{-2}+5\times10^{-3}+4\times10^{-4}+3\times10^{-5}+5\times10^{-6}+4\times10^{-7}+3\times10^{-8}+5\times10^{-9}+\cdots
$$
I don't know what you mean by "denote repetition in algebraic form". Perhaps you would prefer
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(4\times10^{-1}+3\times10^{-2}+5\times10^{-3})\times10^{-3n}
$$

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have a question regarding your second (sigma notation) example: is it really the expanded notation of the number 0.435435..., or is it just one of the ways to express this repeating decimal? As for your first example: although it actually is the expanded notation, How would it look in its algebraic form, and would this algebraic form "fall apart" as soon as we introduce a non-repeating decimal-part before the repeating part? Thank you.

Comment: P.S. What I mean by "algebraic form" here is representing the digits as letters, so that any number similar to 0.435435... is generalized by our algebraic expression (form). I apologize for not clarifying this earlier. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want $.abcabcabc\dots=10^{-1}a+10^{-2}b+10^{-3}c+10^{-4}a+10^{-5}b+10^{-6}c+\cdots$ when you ask for an "algebraic form"?

Comment: For the nonrepeating part, do you want $.abcdecdecde\dots=10^{-1}a+10^{-2}b+10^{-3}c+10^{-4}d+10^{-5}e+10^{-6}c+10^{-7}d+10^{-8}e+\cdots$?

Comment: Can you answer me, bp2017?

Comment: Sorry, I was compelled to be absent. I think your examples in the comment section are pretty good. The only thing I would do is change all the digits to a single letter and use indices instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = \smash[t]{0.\overline{435}}$. Since the pattern repeats every three digits, we can express the number as a geometric sum and find its exact (rational) value that way. Observe:
\begin{align}
&0.\color{red}{435}\color{green}{435}\color{blue}{435}\dots \\
\hline
&0.\color{red}{435} \\
{}+{}\; &0.000\color{green}{435} \\
{}+{}\; &0.000000\color{blue}{435} \\
{}+{}\; &\phantom{0.000000000}\cdots
\end{align}

Using the ancient geometric sum formula (where $|r| < 1$),
$$
a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \cdots = \frac{a}{1-r}, 
$$
we calculate
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{435}{1000^{\phantom{1}}} + \frac{435}{1000^2} 
+ \frac{435}{1000^3} + \cdots \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\frac{435}{1000}}{1 - \frac{1}{1000}} \\[4pt] 
&= \frac{435}{999}
\end{align}
It happens that this fraction reduces, so we might want to write
$$
x = \frac{145}{333}.
$$

---

This generalizes as you might expect, where the denominator ends up being a string of $n$ consecutive $9$s, i.e. the integer $10^n - 1$, where $n$ is the length of the repeating block.

So, for instance, with a block of length $n=2$, the denominator is $10^2-1 = 99$:
$$
0.\overline{47} = 0.474747\dots = \frac{47}{99}
$$

Comment: 1) How do you know this is what OP means by "expanded notation"? 2) Did you check to see whether there were any older questions asking to convert decimals to fractions? I bet there are more than a few, and I bet your answer duplicates answers that have been posted to earlier questions.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Expanded notation is when we multiply each digit of a number by its place value and add all such products together. The 435/999 or 145/333 is not presented in the format described. What are your thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to ask, How would you modify this formula so that it works with numbers that have non-repeating decimal-digits preceding the repeating decimal-digits? Thank you.